# on change error, function expected but got expression

Tags: javascript, tsx

trying to understand why this error is coming up...

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Here's my code:

```js
{ label: "Responsable devis *",
          width: 6,
          select: {
            disabled: isDisabled,
            border: !newBusiness.responsableOfInvoice
              ? "borderwarning"
              : "border",
            placeholder: "Responsable devis",

            defaultValue: newBusiness.responsableOfInvoice,
            items: Object.keys(invoiceResponsableCorres),
            value:
              invoiceResponsableReverseCorres[newBusiness.responsableOfInvoice],
            onChange: (e) => {
              setNewBusiness((vals) => ({
                ...vals,
                responsableOfInvoice:
                  INVOICE_RESPONSABLE[invoiceResponsableReverseCorres[e]],
              }));
              e: invoiceResponsableReverseCorres[INVOICE_RESPONSABLE.SITE];
            },
          },
        },
```

So i know this part is the one that is wrong:

> e: invoiceResponsableReverseCorres[INVOICE_RESPONSABLE.SITE];

But I have tried different ways to resolve this and nothing is working.

Anyone could explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you provided is invalid, here is the valid one:

```js
{
  label: {
    label: "Responsable devis *",
    width: 6,
    select: {
      disabled: isDisabled,
      border: !newBusiness.responsableOfInvoice ? "borderwarning" : "border",
      placeholder: "Responsable devis",

      defaultValue: newBusiness.responsableOfInvoice,
      items: Object.keys(invoiceResponsableCorres),
      value: invoiceResponsableReverseCorres[newBusiness.responsableOfInvoice],
      onChange: (e) => {
        setNewBusiness((vals) => ({
          ...vals,
          responsableOfInvoice: INVOICE_RESPONSABLE[invoiceResponsableReverseCorres[e]],
        }))
      },
      e: ''
    }
  }
}
```